# Concat multiple files in Pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Want to concatenate content of multiple files in single dataframe using pyspark as we can do in pandas.

File 1:

```
1  
2  
3
```

File 2:

```
a  
b  
c  
d
```

Expected Output:

```
1, a  
2, b  
3, c  
 , d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spark = SparkSession.Builder().master(
        <master_url>
    ).config(conf=<spark_config>).appName(<app_name>)
spark_session = spark.getOrCreate()

df = spark_session.read \
     .format("com.databricks.spark.avro") \
     .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
     .load(<csv_path_1>, <csv_path2>)
```

here df will be the spark dataframe.

Note:- install spark_avro jar package before running this code or add below line to your spark config to install spark-avro package.

`"spark.jars.packages": "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0"`